# Dimension of a topological space equals the supremum of the dimension of open subsets in an open cover

Tags: gn.general-topology, dimension-theory

> For a topological space $X$ which is covered by a family of open subsets $\{U_i\}$, show that $\dim(X)=\sup (\dim(U_i))$.

I understand that $\dim(X)\geq \sup(\dim(U_i))$, so it only suffices to show that $\dim(X)\leq \sup(\dim(U_i))$. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What definition of dimension are you using?

Comment: For paracompact spaces the inequality $\dim(X)\le \sup\dim(U_i)$ follows from the Locally finite sum theorem 7.2.3 in "General Topology" of Engelking. For non-paracompact spaces this inequality can be false: consider the (locally compa compact space $X:=([0,\omega_1]\times[0,\omega])\setminus\{(\omega_1,\omega)\}$. It is well-known (and easy to see) that $X$ is not normal and hence $0<Ind(X)\le\dim(X)$. On the other hand, $X$ has a cover by closed-and-open compact zero-dimensional subspaces.

Comment: @Wojowu Here dimension means the supreme of $n$ such that there exists a chain of distinct irreducible closed subsets $Z_0\subset Z_1\cdots \subset Z_n$.

Comment: @TarasBanakh Thank you!

Comment: It'd make sense to include the definitions in the *Question*, including the definition of your understanding of the *irreducible closed set*.

Comment: I strongly support the comment by WlodAA - $\dim$ usually denotes Lebesgue covering dimension, and the comment of @TarasBanakh if I am not mistaken is about this dimension. While from your comment it becomes clear that you have in mind Krull dimension, which is something entirely different.

Answer (score 7):

We want to show that if $X$ has a chain $\varnothing\neq Z_0\subsetneq\dots\subsetneq Z_n$ of irreducible subsets, then some $U_i$ contains a chain of irreducible subsets of the same length.

Since $Z_0$ is nonempty, it contains some point $z$. Let $U$ be any of the sets $U_i$ which contains $x$. We claim $Z_j\cap U$ is a chain of irreducible subsets of $U$.

First we check $Z_j\cap U$ is irreducible. Indeed, suppose it's a union of two closed sets $A,B$. Then closures of $\bar A,\bar B$ (closures in $X$) and $Z_j\setminus U$ are three closed sets whose union is $Z_j$, hence one of them is equal to $Z_j$. That can't be $Z_j\setminus U$, so it must be one of the other sets, say $\bar A$. But $\bar A\cap U=A$ since $A$ is closed in $U$, so $Z_j\cap U=A$.

Finally, we have to show that the inclusions $Z_j\cap U\subseteq Z_{j+1}\cap U$ are proper. Otherwise, we would get that $Z_j$ and $Z_{j+1}\setminus U$ cover $Z_{j+1}$, so one of them is equal to $Z_{j+1}$ and that must be $Z_j$ since $z\not\in Z_{j+1}\setminus U$.